# Angular 1.5 components not getting variable passed to component

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm new to .component() in Angular 1.5+ and I'm trying to create data in the top level app controller, and pass it to a child component. However, printing to the console gives me undefined in the following example and I'm not sure why.

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="Scripts/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
</head>
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myController as vm">
    <app name="vm.myName"></app>
</body>
</html>
```

app.js

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);

app.controller("myController", ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    console.log("myController!");

   $scope.myName = "Rick";
}]);

app.component("app", {
    template: '<h1>Hello World</h1>',
    bindings: {
        name: '='
    },
    controller: function () {
        console.log(this.name); <-- prints undefined
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that in the controller you are using the `$scope` to define the variable that is getting passed into the component but, in the controller block of the HTML you are using the `this` syntax for passing the variable into the component.

So the line with the problem is.

```
app.controller("myController", ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    console.log("myController!");
   $scope.myName = "Rick";
}]);
```

This is a standard `scope` syntax, but since we are using `this` syntax we need it to be.

```
app.controller("myController", ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    console.log("myController!");
    this.myName = "Rick";
}]);
```

Below is a working example.

<kbd>**JSFiddle Demo**</kbd>

Comment: Ah I was mixing the 2 modes. Thank you much!

Answer (score 0):

It is because you are trying to access it too soon. There is a component lifecycle hook called `$onInit`. All bindings will be resolved in that function, so you can use that to access your `name` property.

Try to modify your controller to something like this:

```js
controller: () => {

    this.$onInit = () => {
        console.log(this.name);
    }

}
```

Comment: That makes sense, but still getting undefined.

Comment: It works fine when I pass from one component to another, but when trying to pass that top level controller variable to a component it's giving undefined.

Answer (score 0):

`$onChanges` runs before `$onInit`. You can simply check when your value is passed to your component using this block of code:

```
this.$onChanges = (changesObj) => {
    if(changesObj.name && changesObj.name.currentValue) {
        console.log(this.name);
    }
}
```

You might want to take further look at angularjs 1.5+ components' [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component)

Comment: It's not hitting this console.log() but that is the question. Why isn't the ng-controller variable being passed to the component. I mean I knew it wasn't which is why it was giving me undefined, but why and how do you get it to pass.